# My app is now throwing errors after trying to implement RevMob

Tags: ios, revmob

The Error I am getting is:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type '((Error?) -> Void)!

The code that is causing this error is

```
RevMobAds.startSessionWithAppID("<YOUR_APP_ID>",     
    withSuccessHandler: completionBlock, 
    andFailHandler: failureBlock)
```

Has anybody had this error when using RevMob before or have any ideas on how to fix? Thanks

The error that I am getting:
[image: Error Getting Thrown]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using the new Xcode and Swift 3.0. There have been a few changes on how Objective-C is converted to swift.

You only have to change the `errorBlock` code from what we have in our documentation to this:

```
let errorBlock: ((Error?) -> Void)! = {error in   //  <==  only this line changed
    // check the error
    print(error)
}
```

and add the parameter name to the `startSession` call:

```
RevMobAds.startSession(withAppID: "<YOUR_APP_ID>",   //  only this line changed
                                        withSuccessHandler: completionBlock,
                                        andFailHandler: errorBlock);
```